# Knockout, ¿could the binding name be dynamic (a variable)?

Tags: knockout.js

As knockout official documentation says ([The data-bind syntax](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-syntax.html)), a binding has a *name* and a *value*:

```
<span data-bind="name: value"></span>
```

**¿Can the *name* part be set dynamically with a variable?**
`eval` doesn´t work here.

Background:
I have a bunch of properties that can be regular text, an url, a phone number, an isbn, etc. I also have custom bindings for some of them so I need to apply for each one the binding that suits best...programatically.

```
//viewmodel props
this.url1 = ko.observable(...);
this.text1 =  ko.observable(...);
this.isbn1 = ko.observable(...);
...

var metaProps = [   
  { name: 'url1', binding: 'url' },
  { name: 'text1', binding: 'text' },
  { name: 'isbn1', binding: 'isbn' },
...
]
```

The key here is that the props of my viewmodel depends on the specific subtype of the model object so i dont want to implement a custom HTML template for each subtype (too many). Right now my template looks like:

```
//HTML      
<div data-bind='foreach: { data: metaProps }'>
  <!-- ko if: binding == 'url' -->  
    <span data-bind="url: $parent[name]">   
  <!-- /ko -->                                   
  <!-- ko if: binding == 'isbn' --> 
    <span data-bind="isbn: $parent[name]">  
  <!-- /ko -->              
  <!-- ko if: binding == 'text' --> 
    <span data-bind="text: $parent[name]">  
  <!-- /ko -->  
  ...
</div>
```

My goal is to simplify html to something like:

```
<div data-bind='foreach: { data: metaProps }'> 
    <span data-bind="binding: $parent[name]">     
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a (sadly undocumented) utility function `applyBindingsToNode` that would allow you to create a custom binding that would probably do what you want:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dynamicBinding = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var bindings = {};
        var bindingData = valueAccessor();
        bindings[bindingData['binding']] = bindingContext.$data[bindingData['name']];
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, bindings, bindingContext);
    }
};
```

And call it like this:

```html
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: metaProps, as: 'metaProp' }">
    <span data-bind="dynamicBinding: metaProp"></span>
</div>
```

### Edit:

I like the idea of components, as suggested by @Tomalak, since it allows for much greater flexibility in markup. A small example to demonstrate:

To register the components:

```
ko.components.register('isbn', {
    viewModel: function(params) {
        this.content = params.content;
    },
    template: '<span data-bind="text: content"></span>'
});

ko.components.register('url', {
    viewModel: function(params) {
        this.content = params.content;
    },
    template: '<a data-bind="attr: { href: content }, text: content"></a>'
});
```

Edit your metaProps object a little so the naming is more clear:

```
var metaProps = [   
  { content: this.url1, component: 'url' },
  { content: this.text1, component: 'text' },
  { content: this.isbn1, component: 'isbn' },
...
]
```

And then call the `component` binding to load the components.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: metaProps, as: 'metaProp' }">
    <!-- ko component: { name: metaProp.component, params: { content: metaProp.content } } -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would work with [templates](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html), because:

- It allows for much greater flexibility with regard to formatting and data handling: You are not locked into using the same `<span>` for all your items, every template can be different.
- It's reusable, i.e. you can render an `isbn` consistently anywhere in your view. It might even replace the need for a custom binding handler for ISBNs entirely.
- It results in a clean and straightforward view and model.

```js
// as a mockup of your real "isbn" handler let's just use "text"
ko.bindingHandlers.isbn = ko.bindingHandlers.text;

ko.applyBindings({
  metaProps: [
    {type: 'text', value: 'Some sample text'},
    {type: 'isbn', value: '978-1491914311'},
    {type: 'url', value: 'https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html', text: 'Knockout Docs'}
  ]
});
```

```css
.isbn {font-family: monospace;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="foreach: metaProps">
  <div data-bind="template: 'template-' + type"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/html" id="template-text">
  <span data-bind="text: value"></span>
</script>
<script type="text/html" id="template-isbn">
  <span class="isbn" data-bind="isbn: value"></span>
</script>
<script type="text/html" id="template-url">
  <a data-bind="attr: {href: value}, text: text"></a>
</script>
```

If you like [components](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-binding.html) better, that's an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can resolve your complete problem, but you can generate html dynamically.

```js
function VM(){

var self = this;
self.metaProps = [   
  { name: 'url1', val: '<a href="https://google.com">url</a>' },
  { name: 'text1', val: 'text' },
  { name: 'isbn1', val: 'isbn' },
]

}
ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach:metaProps"> 
    <span data-bind="html:val"><br/>     
</div>
```